# Changing QLabel of PyQt from other python script

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5, uicontrol

Script1 has Qlabel
and Script2 is calculating some value.

What I want to is change Content of Qlabel from coding in Script 2.

For example, I wrote

```
self.button_A.clicked.connect(test)
```

I wrote,

```
import script1

def test():
    self.label_A.setText("this is changed text")
```

on script 2.

And as run result, self is not defined...

I have no idea what happened.

Answer (score 0):

That `self` refers to an object created from the class where you defined your `button_A`.

For example if the code is like the following:

```
class MyWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.button_A = QtGui.QPushButton("Button A", self)
        self.button_A.clicked.connect(test)
```

and you instantiated the object with:

```
my_window = MyWindow()
```

then you have to have a reference to that `my_window` in the Script 2 and invoke the command with:

```
from script1 import my_window

my_window.label_A.setText("this is changed text")
```

Comment: You can't get the same error running changed Script 2 as there's no `self` in it.